# Graphing a parabola in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graph

I have the maths working correctly in a calculations class and can correctly calculate the horizontal/vertical components and the time taken for the object to land as well as the final horizontal displacement.

I'd like to know how to graph the parabola in vb forms, using classes if possible. I know I'll probably have to use a picture box but I'm not familiar with how they work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't really need to know anything about a `PictureBox` control specifically. It's just a control. Add one to your form in the designer like you would any other control. In order to draw a graph on it, you'll need to use GDI+. That means handling the `Paint` event of that control and using the `Graphics` object it provides to draw on the control. In your case, you'll want to have all your `Points` in an array and call `DrawLines`. The more `Points` you have, the more like a smooth curve the series of lines will appear.

Comment: `I'm not familiar with how they work`  **easily** researched.  this is not a tutorial site, please read [ask] and take the [tour]